# NCO (NetCDF operators) doesnt seem to have installed ncrcat (Anaconda)

Tags: anaconda, netcdf, nco

So I've installed nco using the following command: `conda install -c conda-forge nco` which gives me nco version 7.8.1

However, when I try to run `ncrcat` I get:

> `ncrcat` is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.

Other commands work fine. This suggests `ncrcat` has not been installed, how do I install that?

Answer (score 1):

The behavior you describe is unlikely unless you are using Windows, in which case the solution is to copy `ncra.exe` to `ncrcat.exe` more or less like this:

```
copy ncra.exe ncrcat.exe
```

Comment: I am on windows, yes; sorry forgot that detail.

Where would I type this?

Comment: In a DOS window in the directory where ncra.exe was installed

Comment: So I think the folder anconda installs to is "C:\Users\Evan\Anaconda3\pkgs\nco-4.8.1-habc9422_100\Library\bin"

I copied the file, but I get the same error.
Any ideas?

Comment: Wait no, there was another one in "C:\Users\Evan\Anaconda3\Library\bin", and that worked. thankyou